# Error:can only bind lists of raw vectors (or null)

Tags: r, sqldf

I have two data frame x and y. I am trying two merge this two data frame using sqldf function in R.

Sqldf::sqldf( select * from x join y on x.key=y.key)
But this gives me error

Error:can only bind lists of raw vectors (or null)

I tried separately to run and both of them works
Sqldf::sqldf( select * from x) or
Sqldf::sqldf( select * from y).

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput(head(x, 10))` and `dput(head(y, 10))`